# IntelliJ IDEA - Asterisk after author's name in git log

Tags: intellij-idea, git-commit, jetbrains-ide

In our git log we sometimes see an asterisk after the user name in the *Author* column. The same user is listed without the asterisk in other commits.

What does the asterisk stand for?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.6.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000105210-VCS-Annotate-is-bold-and-has-star

Comment: @CrazyCoder: No, that is about an asterisk in the _annotate ouput_, not in the log.

Comment: It means that these lines belongs to current revision (last commit pulled from remote branch)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html#annotate_blame

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Every change in GIT (and in the most of modern VCS's) has an author and a committer. The Log shows an author because we respect authorship even if the author of changes doesn't have access to the repo or isn't able to commit code by himself.

Asterisk on the author's name in the Log means that this commit was created by the described person, but was applied by someone else.

Here is an illustration of how it looks:
[image]

There are some common cases when this happens:

- you cherrypicked someone else's commit
- you rebased branch with someone else's commits
- you applied `.patch` file mailed to you by someone else
- you merged the pull-request via GitHub UI - GitHub does it with its own user but leaves authorship to you.

Answer (score 21):

It indicates that commit is the most recent commit to modify the file.

> Annotations for lines modified in the current revision are marked with a bold type and an asterisk.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html#annotate_blame

Comment: This is about blame in the source file. Asterisk in VCS log has different meaning

Comment: ah yes thank you, the question is a bit ambiguous. I'll leave this here for others as a sign marker because it's what I was searching for when I found this question by context. Your answer is very good, and should be the accepted one for this pointed question.

Comment: I have a few files where there is no asterisk next to a committer's name. What does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

That (the asterisk) is usually when another user has rebased the commits of the original author. You can confirm this in the message window on the lower right. It will show you the original author along with "committed by" with the name of the user who did the rebase.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the source provided by @CrazyCoder the asterisk indicates that the branch was created by a different user.

Answer (score 0):

I think it signifies a commit issue.  I see it in my company's codebase in what I believe is a missed merge.  I see it with a Git log --graph command as well as in Intellij.  This isn't suppose to happen, but it appears that there are two remote branches, BA and BB, both from the master.

1. Developer Alice checks out remote branch BA.
2. Developer Bob checks out remote branch BB and merges in changes in the master branch.
3. Alice updates, commits, and pushes her local BA to the remote BA.
4. Alice makes a pull request to get her change in the master branch.
5. Meanwhile, Bob has committed and pushed his changes to BB.
6. Merge master Meg performs the pull.

So BB, which Bob committed after Meg merged Alice's change to BA, does not contain the changes.  In other words, BB is based on the pre-BA changes.  Git is smart enough to see the problem and alert you with this obscure, seemingly undocumented feature.

I'm a n00b when it comes to Git, so I may be wrong.  Look for commit issues with the asterisked commit.

Answer (score -1):

The Asterisk in Intellij blame

lines marked by asterisk in Intellij blame means that those lines are commit of the last / most recent commit in the code.

here is the link with more details.

Click [here][https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html#annotate_blame:~:text=Annotations%20for%20lines%20modified%20in%20the%20current%20revision%20are%20marked%20with%20a%20bold%20type%20and%20an%20asterisk.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html#annotate_blame:%7E:text=Annotations%20for%20lines%20modified%20in%20the%20current%20revision%20are%20marked%20with%20a%20bold%20type%20and%20an%20asterisk.)

Comment: Why did you post this answer that duplicates the previous one?